# VS Code - logpoints not showing filename/line number

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for Angular & NodeJS/Express development. Using Node/Express for backend API up until now I could run the API using F5, add logpoints and when reached it would show the filename & line number; I could click on it and be taken to the breakpoint.

Upgraded to 1.47.1 and it's not displaying that info any more; now it displays "<node_internals>/logpoint-[hexchars].cdp". Clicking on this shows:

```
console.log("%O", (() => {
  try {
    return err;
  } catch (e) {
    return e.stack || e.message || String(e);
  }
})())
//# sourceURL=logpoint-ffe6686.cdp
```

Haven't touched any VS Code configurations. I uninstalled 1.47.1, deleted .vscode folder, installed 1.40 and the original behavior came back (filename/line #). Updated VS Code and new behavior happens.

Can't find anything on the web and not sure what the problem is.

Am I missing something simple? Anyone running into this?

Thanks.